# Must these two elements in a vector space be the same?

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider an element $x$ in a vector space $X$.

On the one hand, by scalar multiplication, we have an element $(-1)\cdot x$.

On the other hand, the inverse element of $x$ is an element $x'$ such that $x+x'=0$, where $0$ is the identity element such that $x+0=0+x=x$ for all $x$ in $X$. The inverse element is based solely on addition.

Must $x'$ be the same as $(-1)\cdot x$? In other words, the addition and scalar multiplication for a vector space are not independent.

Comment: Use the axioms to prove that $x+(-1)x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @azif00's hint.

$x+(-1)x=(1+(-1))x=0x$. (Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition)
\begin{gather*}
0x+x\\
=(0+1)x \quad (\text{Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition})\\
=1x\\
=x \quad (\text{The unit rule})
\end{gather*}

The same logic leads to $x+0x=x$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
x' &= x'+\vec{0}\\ 
&=x'+0\cdot x\\
&=x'+(1+(-1))\cdot x\\
&=x'+(1\cdot x + (-1)\cdot x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,   (***)\\
&=(x'+1\cdot x) + (-1)\cdot x\\
&=\vec0+(-1)\cdot x\\
&=(-1)\cdot x\\
\end{align}

(This might have used some facts that are not in your set of axioms, like perhaps $0\cdot x = \vec 0$. But all the steps, if they are not axioms, are easily derivable from axioms.)

Notice that at step $(***)$ we used the fact that addition of scalars distributes over multiplication by scalars. "Distributivity" is quite often the way that different operations are not independent of each other.